# Type of String into Type of Int

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm trying to convert a string into an Int but every time I do it gives me an error.

For example, I have `UILabel` and it calls `resultLabel`. Also I have a `UITextField`.
So what I'm trying to do is first `UITextField` + second `UITextField` = resultLabel.

Bottom line, I want from the user to put a number in each `UITextField` to get the final answer in the `resultLabel`.

For instance 1 + 1 = 2. But my app gives me 11 or error.

```
var numberOnScreen:Int = 0

@IBOutlet var first: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var second: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var resultLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func calculate(_ sender: Any) {
    numberOnScreen = Int(first.text!)!
    numberOnScreen = Int(second.text!)!
    resultLabel.text! = first.text! + second.text!
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing string concatenation.

First make sure your textfield text are not `nil` & convert `string` to `int` and it can be `nil`. So you have use `if let` to make sure the converted values are not `nil`

```
if let firstText = firstTextfield.text, let secondText = secondTextfield.text, let firstValue = Int(firstText), let secondValue = Int(secondText) {
    let plusValue = firstValue + secondValue
}
```

Comment: Yes, It will not go inside the if condition. You have to write `else` in that case

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you use `+` with `String`, it mean you are concatenating two strings.

So "1" + "1" = "11"

Try it to resolve your problem:

```
@IBAction func calculate(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let first = first.text, let second = second.text, let firstNum = Int(first), let secondNum = Int(second)  else {
        return
    }

    let result = firstNum + secondNum

    resultLabel.text = String(result)
}
```